# How can I check if SQLite database is open in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I want to be able to check if a given SQLite database is open or not. How can I do this in C/C++? I looked around the SQLite C/C++ API and did not see something apparent for this purpose.

Comment: Your question needs clarification, or preparation for the barrage of "What did [`sqlite3_open()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) return?".

Comment: Well, you *have* called [`sqlite3_open`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html), haven't you? Then you should have checked that the database was opened then and there, otherwise you should handle the error gracefully (and if the database is critical for the functioning of your application that error handling would probably have been to exit the program).

Comment: @WhozCraig and Joachim Pileborg: the link to the mailing list from NicholasM's answer below answers my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As WhozCraig first mentioned, you need to check the return value of `sqlite3_open`.  If the return code is SQLITE_OK, the database has been opened.  You probably will also want to check that the pointer parameter was not set to null.

This is [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) on the interface for that function.

[Here](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/How-do-you-check-if-a-sqlite-database-is-open-td19815.html) is a mailing list post in which someone explains why there isn't an isOpen function:

> An app cannot use an sqlite3 handle unless open has succeeded, so there is 
>   no need for an is-opened function. That couldn't possibly work because 
>   sqlite3_open() allocates the sqlite3 handle, meaning the client cannot have 
>   a valid handle until after sqlite3_open() succeeds. To see if it's opened, 
>   check the pointer to see if it's NULL (which you of course must initialize 
>   it to, or else it has an unspecified value).
>
> ...
>
> After you close it, assign it to NULL again, and there's your "is open" 
>   flag.

By the way, creating a DatabaseHandle class using [RAII](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) is strongly suggested.  That way, your program will be sure to call [`sqlite3_close`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html) with the `sqlite3` object when you are finished.  From the documentation of `sqlite3_open`:

> Whether or not an error occurs when it is opened, resources associated
>   with the database connection handle should be released by passing it
>   to sqlite3_close() when it is no longer required.

Comment: I disagree, that there is no need for a isopen function, while its open something may happend like a crash of the library or the file gets changed by another app (shouldnt be possible, but you never know...)